# Supplying profile name for Spring Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am using Spring Profiles in my Spring Boot application by setting the property `spring.profiles.active` in the **application.properties** file.

But if I use the JVM system parameter way of supplying the profile name with the `spring.profiles.active` property still present in the file, will it override the file value?

The JVM system parameter way:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Starting with maven or with java because its already built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be present in the file. Command line argument will take precedence over file properties.

These profiles will be activated during application startup.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks